# TabHost and/or ViewFlipper DialogProblem

Tags: android, dialog, android-context

I have some problems with the `TabHost` and `ViewFlipper`.

Here are the `ViewFlipper` as I expect the answer to this will also do the job in the `TabHost`.

I would like to have a Custom Dialog shown when the user reach a certain stage, but I can not figure out which `Context` to hand it?

```
final Dialog congratsDialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
congratsDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
congratsDialog.setContentView(R.layout.congrats_dialog);
TextView name = (TextView) congratsDialog.findViewById(R.id.congratsDialogName);
name.setText(player.getName());
```

This will result in a `NullPointerException` in the line were I try to `setText`.

I have also tried `flipper.getContext()`, `getBaseContext()`, `getApplicationContext()` and have also tried other crazy thing but every time I get a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

setContentView() to dialog is trade off over android version if you are using android 2.0 or less it would not work use versions 2.0 or above for this function. Otherwise if you want to do for all version then use setContentView(View) where View is from xml layout of congrats dialog after inflating it.

Please try this and let me know if you got solution.